# Allow multiple selection of image in mediafinder field

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am trying to allow users to select multiple images in a mediafinder field - using the Builder plugin.

I have tried:

```
public $attachMany = [
    'tour_images' => ['System\Models\File', 'order' => 'sort_order']
];
```

But this does not work.

What am I doing wrong and is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you should check the following link: https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/1658